# How to create a test script if data is updated

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am creating a test script where I want to make sure data are modified.

```
def test_mission_if_collabor_and_user_are_the_same(self):
        """ If the user is also written as the collaborator,
        Mission should not duplicate"""

        #Check length of missions return 2
        actuser = ActuserViewModel(self.user_name[0], 'M')
        actuser.get_mission_list(self.user_name[0])

        #Check if it shows the mission list
        self.assertEqual(len(actuser.missionList), 2)

        #update one of the missions where collaborator is the same as the user

        # Call view by POST method

        mission = MissionViewModel(self.mission_id_list[0])
        missionForm = MissionForm(data={'name': 'test name','collaborator':'useraaaa'}, instance=mission.db)
        mission.save_to_actinbox()

        #save updated test

        missionCheck = MissionViewModel(self.mission_id_list[0])
        self.assertEqual(missionCheck.db.collaborator, 2)
```

I am not confident with this part of coding, systax might be not correct because it does not show that the data have been updated

```
missionForm = MissionForm(data={'name': 'test name','collaborator':'useraaaa'}, instance=mission.db)
```

Comment: Since you have posted only parts of your code it's hard to reach a conclusion, however it appears that you are checking Mission held by the test class rather than testing mission objects in the database.  While I also tend to write some long drawn out tests, purists will argue that your unit test is far too complex.

Comment: Am I wrong or are you actually trying to test Django itself? I would expect that a model update will always result to a data update, or Django itself is not testing something right then.